# C# - Accessing a list of Objects from one class to another

Tags: c#, .net

I am having this very strange problem where i am creating a list of some objects in one class then trying to access it in another class but it's coming empty in other class:

My first class where i am populating the list:

```
namespace dragdrop
{
    struct BR
    {
        private string var;
        public string Var
        {
            get { return var; }
            set { var = value; }
        }
        private string equalsTo;

        public string EqualsTo
        {
            get { return equalsTo; }
            set { equalsTo = value; }
        }
        private string output;

        public string Output
        {
            get { return output; }
            set { output = value; }
        }
        private string els;

        public string Els
        {
            get { return els; }
            set { els = value; }
        }
        private string elsOutput;

        public string ElsOutput
        {
            get { return elsOutput; }
            set { elsOutput = value; }
        }



    }
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    //******************
        private List<BR> list = new List<BR>(); //This is the list!
    //******************

        internal List<BR> List
        {
            get { return list; }
            set { list = value; }
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] vars = new string[] { "Name", "Gender", "Age", "Address", "email" };

            comboBox1.DataSource = vars;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BR b = new BR();
            b.Var = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            b.EqualsTo = textBox1.Text;
            b.Output = textBox2.Text;
            list.Add(b);
    //*****************
            textBox1.Text = List.Count.ToString(); //This gives the correct count value!
    //*****************
            //this.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

I am accessing it in second class like:

```
namespace dragdrop
{
    public partial class Ribbon1
    {
        private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 form = new Form1();
            List<BR> l = form.List; ;         
            //*******************
            MessageBox.Show(form.List.Count.ToString()); //This strangely gives count 0!
            //*******************
        }

    }
}
```

I have even tried making everything public in first class but no matter what i do, im always getting empty list in second class.

Comment: you fill your list on button click, but try access to newly created Form1, where you not click to button, and not fill your list

Comment: @Grundy the list should be filled when i click the second button, im doing them in order.. first form1 click then the second class click

Comment: you are actually creating a new object of `Form1` and accessing the list without initializing

Comment: on your `Ribbon1.button1_Click` you create **new Form1** every time

Comment: hmm, how to solve it? i tried directly accessing List using Form1.List but it gives me an error saying non static members must be accessed through objects

Comment: what is `Ribbon1`? your custom class?

Comment: im actually writing a word plugin so i created a ribbon for it and this class is auto generated.

Comment: Well you aren't loading anything into your list in the form constructor or form_load so what do you expect to be in your list? Your list only gets populated when ppl click a button on the form.

Comment: @failedprogramming i am loading an object in the list on a button click in the form

Comment: yeah but when you click a button on your ribbon, the button in the form is not clicked so nothing will be in your list.

Comment: as i said i am doing it in order.. i first click the button in form (at that point list contains an element) after that i click button in ribbon but that element disappears then

Comment: Write a constructor that will accept the `List<BR>` in `Ribbon1` class and pass the `List` you want.

Comment: why can't i access it the way i am?? whats the mistake?

Comment: You are not understanding me correctly. in your ribbon button1_Click(), you create a new form. Then you show the list count in a messagebox. You create a string array and assign to your combobox. Nothing else happens during this code. If you click your form button later, it will not affect this messagebox in any way.

Comment: @AbdulJabbar It seems you are lacking some fundamental understanding of object oriented programming, therefore it is very hard to give you proper advice. Do look up instances vs classes in an introductory course / book / whatever.

Comment: What you're doing boils down to: `Form1 a = new Form1(); a.button1_Click(); Form1 b = new Form1(); b.List.Count.ToString();`. `a.List` contains items, but `b.List` does not, because you called `button1_Click()` on `a`, not on `b`. In your `Ribbon1` code, you need to get a reference to the `Form1` instance that you called `button1_Click` on, instead of creating a new `Form1`.

Comment: that's what i am not able to do, get reference of Form1 instance in Ribbon class

Comment: so try add form as field in ribbon class, how you show your form?

Comment: Where are you creating your `Ribbon1` instance? Is it part of `Form1`?

Answer (score 1):

The is no relation what-so-ever between `Form1` and `Ribbon1`, how can one then access an instance of the other?

With this:

```
        Form1 form = new Form1(); // new instance of Form1
        List<BR> l = form.List; ; // of course the list is empty in a new instance!
```

you can never access values from another instance of `Form1`.

Since I have no idea how your classes are connected I cannot give you more advice than have a look at [this good overview of OO-relationships.](http://www.slideshare.net/tahersb/object-oriented-relationships) You have to connect them somehow for it to work, I would very much recommend composition // aggregation (same thing, different schools).

Answer (score -1):

All i needed to do was make the list a static member in class one, that solved the issue of having different value when i tried to create a new instance of Form1 in Ribbon1 class.

```
private static List<BR> list = new List<BR>();
```

Comment: If you have multiple `Form1` instances, they will now all share the same `List`. Sometimes that's what you want, but often it is not. So it may work in this case, but it's not really a good solution.

Comment: That is not a very good solution, as Pieter says; it doesn't handle multiple instances of `Form1`, what happens if you have multiple instances of Word open at the same time?

Comment: Honestly and without any offense, you are lacking very important and basic programming skills. If this is a work related thing it is going probably to fail. I recommend you getting some training.